# Google maps - computeDistanceBetween not working

Tags: javascript, api, maps, distance

I have read some issues with calculate distance on google maps API but still not working for me. Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
   var loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897);
   var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.1633766,-81.6487862);

   console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(loc1,loc2));
}
```

This is how I call library:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

But I still get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'spherical' of undefined
    at initMap

What I'm doing wrong? Do I have to enable some custom API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the 'libraries' parameter in your  src url twice.

Remove the second one:
&libraries=places

...and keep the first one:
&libraries=geometry,places

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: No problem. Sometimes just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with request url, **libraries** parameter duplicates.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

In order to use spherical class you have to include 'geometry' into requesting libraries list - check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#SphericalGeometry) :

```
// This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
```